# Type mismatch between columns in GET query. How to define returning column type when only NULL is returned?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an existing empty DataTable with 4 columns A, B, C, D:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable
{
    Columns = 
    {
        new DataColumn("A", typeof(string)){ AllowDBNull = true },
        new DataColumn("B", typeof(string)){ AllowDBNull = true },
        new DataColumn("C", typeof(string)){ AllowDBNull = true },
        new DataColumn("D", typeof(string)){ AllowDBNull = true }
    }
}
```

And I would like to fill that table with data from the database. The database contains only the columns C and D, So I would like to fill the first 2 columns with NULLs.

So I call:

```
await using DbConnection connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.db");
await using DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
string selectCommand = $"SELECT NULL as 'A', NULL as 'B', C, D FROM Table ";
command.CommandText = selectCommand;

await connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
await using DbDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
dataTable.Load(reader);
await connection.CloseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Once I get to that line:

```
dataTable.Load(reader);
```

the app crashes with an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Inconvertible type mismatch between SourceColumn 'A' of Byte[] and the DataColumn 'A' of String.'
```

Is it possible to modify the code, so that the returning column 'A' will not be byte[] but a string. I tried using:

```
string selectCommand = $"SELECT CAST(NULL as TEXT) as 'A', CAST(NULL as TEXT) as 'B', C, D FROM Table ";
```

But it does not work. It throws the same exception.
It works when I use empty strings rather than NULLS, but I would like them to be NULL without any additional iterative work.

Comment: Did you try to NOT select anything for columns A and B and leave them at their defaults?

Comment: Also I don't think you should put the columns A and B inside single quotes. They should be As A and As B

Comment: Ok, it works when I don't mention these columns. 
I am not sure about using A rather than 'A'. What if it is not 'A', but text with spaces ala 'A AAA AAA'. Not using quotes will break the query, and I would rather use the same coding style all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Steve gave me a solution that seems to work.
You just need to avoid using the first 2 columns:

```
string selectCommand = $"SELECT C, D FROM Table ";
```